# I want to find exact term of sub string, exact term not just part of the term

Tags: elasticsearch

I have group of json documents from wikidata (http://www.wikidata.org) to index to elasticsearch for search.
It has several fields. For example, it looks like below.

```
{
   eId:Q25338
   eLabel:"The Little Prince, Little Prince",
   ...
}
```

Here, what I want to do is for user to search 'exact term', not part of the term. Meaning, if a user search 'prince', I don't want to show this document in the search result. When user types the whole term 'the little prince' or 'little prince', I want to make this json included in the search result, namely.

- Should I pre-process all the comma separate sentence (some eLabel has tens of elements in the list) and make it bunch of different documents and make the keyword term field respectively?
- If not, how can I make a mapping file to make this search as expected?

My current Mappings.json.

```
  "mappings": {
    "entity": {
      "properties": {
        "eLabel": { # want to replace
          "type": "text" ,
          "index_options": "docs" ,
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        } ,
        "eid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "subclass": {
          "type": "boolean"
        } ,
        "pLabel": {
          "type": "text" ,
          "index_options": "docs" ,
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        } ,
        "prop_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "pType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "way": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "chain": {
          "type": "integer"
        } ,
        "siteKey": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "docId": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I pre-process all the comma separate sentence (some eLabel has tens of elements in the list) and make it bunch of different documents and make the keyword term field respectively?

This is exactly what you should do. Elasticsearch can't process the comma-separated list for you. It will think your data is just 1 whole string. But if you preprocess it, and then make the resulting field a [Keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) field, that will work very well - it's exactly what the Keyword field type is designed for. I'd recommend using a [Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to search for exact matches. (As opposed to a Match query, a Term query [does not analyse the incoming query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#avoid-term-query-text-fields) and is thus more efficient.)

Comment: Yeah, I see. I should do the thing. Thank you. It helps a lot.